# in SwiftUI, I have 2 Entities (A & B) in my CoreData with a relationship (one to many) between them, how can I fetch all attributes of B in TextFields

Tags: swiftui, core-data, relationship, textfield, xcode14

Let's say I have 2 entities:

1. **GameSession** :which has Attributes "date", "place", "numberofplayer" + a relationship called "players" with "Player"
2. **Player**: which has Attributes "name","score_part1","score_part2","score_part3" + a relationship with "GameSession"

the relationship is "one to many": One session can have many players

Let's say now I have a list of GameSession and when I click on on one (with a NavigationLink)
It sends me to a new view where I can see:
All the names of the players of that session (in text) and also right next to the player name I would like to have 3 TextField in which I can enter (an update) "score_part1","score_part2","score_part3" for every players of that session

Basically I am able to display the name of all the players of a given session, But it seems impossible to have the "score_part1","score_part2","score_part3" in editable TextField...

I have an error saying "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'"

**Basically in my first view I have something like that**:

```
struct RamiListePartieUIView: View {@Environment(.managedObjectContext) var moc@FetchRequest(entity: GameSession.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \GameSession.date, ascending: false)]) var gamesessions: FetchedResults<GameSession>

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(gamesessions, id: \.date) { session in
                NavigationLink (destination: DetailPartieSelecUIView(session: session)){
                    Text("\(session.wrappedPlace) - le \(session.wrappedDate, formatter: itemFormatter) ")
                }
                
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteSessions)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
}
```

**And in my second view I have something like that**:

```
struct DetailPartieSelecUIView: View {
    @State var session:GameSession
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        Section("Ma session du \(session.wrappedDate, formatter: itemFormatter)"){
            
            ForEach(session.playersArray, id: \.self) { player in
                
                HStack {
                    Text(player.wrappedName)       //  OK it works
                    TextField("score", text : player.wrappedScore_part1) //  it generates an error
                    TextField("score", text : player.wrappedScore_part2) //  it generates an error
                    TextField("score", text : player.wrappedScore_part3) //  it generates an error
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
        //    formatter.dateStyle = .short
        //    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
            formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd" //"YY/MM/dd"
            return formatter
}()
```

also,
I have defined the "wrappedScore_part1","wrappedScore_part2","wrappedScore_part3" in the Player+CoreDataProperties.swift file

and "wrappedPlace", "wrappedData" as well as the "PlayersArray" in the GameSession+CoreDataProperties.swift file

it is done like that:

```
public var wrappedPlace: String {
    place ?? "Unknown"
}

// Convert NSSet into an array of "Player" object
public var playersArray: [Player] {
    let playersSet = players as? Set<Player> ?? []

    return playersSet.sorted {
        $0.wrappedName< $1.wrappedName
    }
}
```

I am new at coding with swiftUI so I am probably doing something wrong... If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

I have tried a lot of things. Like changing the type of my attribute to Int32 instead os String. As I am suppose to enter numbers in those fields, I thought it would be best to have Integer. But it didn't change anything. and ultimately I had the same kind of error message

I tried also to add the $ symbol, like that:

```
TextField("score", text : player.$wrappedScore_part1)
```

But then I had other error message popping up at the row of my "ForEach", saying "Cannot convert value of type '[Player]' to expected argument type 'Binding'"
And also on the line just after the HStack, I had an error saying "Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding' conform to 'StringProtocol'"

Thank you for your help!
Best regards,
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem of how to fetch the players in a session you need to supply a predicate to the `@FetchRequest<Player>`, e.g.

```
@FetchRequest
private var players: FetchedResults<Player>

    init(session: Session) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "session = %@", session)
        let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\Player.timestamp)] // need something to sort by.
        _players = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate)
    }
```

That acts like a filter and will only return the players that have the session relation equalling that object. The reason you have to fetch like this is so any changes will be detected.

The second problem about the bindings can be solved like this:

```
struct PlayerView: View{
    @ObservedObject var player: Player {

    var body:some View {
        if let score = Binding($player.score) {
            TextField("Score", score)
        }else{
            Text("Player score missing")
        }
    }
}
```

This View takes the player object as an ObservedObject so body will be called when any of its properties change and allows you to get a binding to property. The Binding init takes an optional binding and returns a non-optional, allowing you to use it with a `TextField`.

Comment: Hi @malhal and thank you for your answer.
I am not sure where to  specify NSPredicate(format: "session = %@", session)
as I am not really fetching the players.
In the first view I fetch the GameSession
And in the second view, I loop over the array of players in that session, but I didn t do any fetching per say...

Comment: you need to use another fetch request for the players so it can detect changes

Comment: thank you. So I need to fetch inside my ForEach loop?

Comment: Hi @malhal, it's me again. :)
So, I tried to put:

@FetchRequest(entity: Player.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Player.name, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "session == %@", session)) var players: FetchedResults<Player>

Comment: Hi @malhal,
I tried to put in my second view, just below the declaration of my variable moc:
@FetchRequest(entity: Player.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Player.name, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "session == %@", session)) var players: FetchedResults<Player>

But I get an error message
"Cannot use instance member 'session' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

But If I put it in my var body, I have the message:

"Cannot declare local wrapped variable in result builder"

So I am lost...

Comment: I added some code to my answer to demonstrate

Comment: Hi @malhal. Thank you for the updated code. I am now able to fetch the players of that session. Now I am doing the ForEach like that: "ForEach(players, id: \. wrappedName) { player in ...."
But I still can't use the TextField component to modify the attribute of a player. If I use your code with Binding($player.score), I have an error saying "Cannot find '$player' in scope".... And if I don't put the $ symbol, I am having the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<Value?>'"... Thank you

Comment: You need to supply the player to a subview that has `@ObservedObject var player: Player` then you can use `$player.score` in its `body`. Note, this is only because its from a `FetchRequest`, if it was a simple array of structs then we could simply do `ForEach($structArray) { $struct in`

Comment: Hi @malhal. Thank you, I tried your solution (supply the player to a subview). But I have an error message when I want to use the TextField. The error is: "Cannot assign to property: 'wrappedScore' is a get-only property"
I have no problem to display via "Text" all the properties of a given player. But I can't use TextField to modify those properties... Thank you

Comment: You need another View and @ObservedObject. I've added some more code to my answer.

Comment: thank you for your patience! It's finally working fine!
Have a good sunday!

Comment: Hi @malhal, I have posted an other question regarding the same project. If you have a few minutes, I would really appreciate your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74883410/a-coredata-computed-property-used-to-sort-an-array-of-object-is-not-updated-wor Thank you